# Detect if source file is empty before using COPY in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am running 64bit Postgres 10.3 on Windows 2012 R2. Every week we get data in text files (44 seperate files) and I use a LOOP and the COPY command in a PL/pgSQL function to import the data. I have come accross an issue where an incorrect password was supplied when unzipping the data, so the source files were created but empty. The import function appeared to be running but would freeze at a different file each time I tried.

Is there any way (using PL/pgSQL) to detect if a file on disk is empty before trying to use COPY?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for this. Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wwusp_filesize(file_path text)
RETURNS TEXT AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_file_size; 
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_file_size (size BIGINT);
 EXECUTE 'COPY tmp_file_size (size) FROM PROGRAM ''wc -c < ' || file_path || '''';
 RETURN (SELECT pg_size_pretty(size) FROM tmp_file_size);
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This will work on Linux servers. If you wish to make it work also on Windows, just replace the `wc -c < file` with the corresponding program/syntax.

```
# SELECT wwusp_filesize('/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf') AS filesize;
  filesize  
------------
 4641 bytes
(1 row)
```

And with an empty file ..

```
# SELECT wwusp_filesize('/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/empty_file') AS filesize;
 filesize 
----------
 0 bytes
(1 row)
```